# Sql query causing MS CRM Dynamics 4.0 slowness issue

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-4, crm

My CRM application uers are facing slowness issue at a particular part of day and it has been found that a SQL query fires(attached below) at 1 PM daily causing the same:

select count(*) from asyncoperationbase where RecurrencePattern is not null
and DeletionStateCode = 0 and consuming server resources.

Pls note that due to some constarints I cannot purge the table. My only concern is how come this query triggers itself? Is it like some maintainance query or routine query as fired by CRM server? Pls suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like it might be related to a clean up job.  It is counting the recurring async operations.  One of Microsoft's fix involves purging the table on a regular basis as detailed here and there is a hotfix that may fix it as well - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968520.  There is a similar article here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968755.  If you have not already, you should upgrade to the latest update rollup since the UR's address these issues.

Comment: Thanks Cole for sharing your analysis. The thing here is that due to some business constraints we cannot follow KB98650. Instead can we INDEX the two tables, if it could be helpful? Pls suggest.

Comment: Absolutely, applying indexes should make your SQL queries go faster and I haven't seen issues with creating them in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know the architechture of your CRM Application. In an ideal scenario the Application server & databse server must be on separate machine. It could be a problem of Architecture

Comment: Thanks Ritesh. You caught it right and you must be knowing the source of respective issue :). Yes, both are on same server and we have to live with it for some time.